# How Do I Install and Run Blender 2.83 on CentOS 7?

Tags: command-line, installation, linux

Trying to use my vps to run Blender server-side.
I've tried a number of tutorials, but no success.

So far...

- https://snapcraft.io/install/blender/centos
- https://wpguru.co.uk/2019/07/how-to-install-blender-on-centos-7/
- https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/about/contribute/install/linux.html

Current error is-- ./blender: error while loading shared libraries: libXi.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Update:
Made some progress by repeatedly running ./blender -v so it would error out and tell me what package was still missing--

- yum install libXtst
- yum install libXxf86vm
- yum install libXrender
- yum install libGL

<<<<<<<<< edit <<<<<<<<<

My attempt to download and run the .zip package from Blender.org:
File unzips, Blender launches from command line, but it can't find any of its directories, config files, etc.

`# ./blender -b`
`Blender 2.83.2 (hash 239fbf7d936f built 2020-07-09 06:21:45)`
`AL lib: (EE) ALCplaybackOSS_open: Could not open /dev/dsp: No such file or directory`
`/run/user/0/gvfs/ non-existent directory`
`found bundled python: /etc/blender-2.83.2-linux64/2.83/python`

`Blender quit`

<<<<<<<<< edit <<<<<<<<<

I think I made some more progress... but I haven't figured out what worked and what didn't. I'll edit this down when I have a clearer idea.

```
# sudo snap install blender
error: system does not fully support snapd: cannot mount squashfs
# modprobe sqhashfs
# rpm -qa kernel\* | sort
kernel-debug-devel-3.10.0-1127.13.1.el7.x86_64
kernel-headers-3.10.0-1127.13.1.el7.x86_64
# dnf install kernel-modules
kernel-3.10.0-1127.13.1.el7.x86_64
kernel-debug-devel-3.10.0-1127.13.1.el7.x86_64
kernel-headers-3.10.0-1127.13.1.el7.x86_64
# rpm -qa kernel\* | sort
# sudo snap install blender --classic
error: system does not fully support snapd: cannot mount squashfs
# sudo yum install libsquashfuse0 squashfuse fuse
# sudo dnf install libsquashfuse0 squashfuse fuse
# rpm install libsquashfuse0 squashfuse fuse
# curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/dvershinin/apt-get-centos/master/apt-get.sh -o /usr/local/bin/apt-get
# sudo apt-get install libsquashfuse0 squashfuse fuse
# sudo: apt-get: command not found
(CentOS 7 does not use apt)
# yum list all
(very long list)
# yum -y install epel-release
# yum repolist
# sudo yum search blender
# sudo yum info blender.x86_64
# sudo yum install blender.x86_64
(yum installed blender 2.68, newest version is 2.9)
# rpm -ql blender.x86_64
# cd blender_docs
# pip install -r requirements.txt
# sudo pip install requirements.txt --upgrade
# make
build succeeded, 1 warning.
```

<<<<<<<<< edit <<<<<<<<<

Now I have blender folders and files in multiple directories, but I can't get any of them to run.

./etc/blender-2.83.2-linux64/blender
./etc/blender-2.83.2-linux64/2.83/scripts/addons/io_scene_gltf2/blender
./usr/lib64/blender
./usr/bin/blender
./usr/share/blender
./usr/share/fonts/blender
./root/.cache/thumbnails/fail/blender
./root/blender
./root/blender-2.83.2-linux64/blender
./root/blender-2.83.2-linux64/2.83/scripts/addons/io_scene_gltf2/blender
./root/.thumbnails/fail/blender

./blender -b usually gets this error:
AL lib: (WW) alc_initconfig: Failed to initialize backend "pulse"

ALSA lib confmisc.c:767:(parse_card) cannot find card '0'

ALSA lib conf.c:4568:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_card_driver returned error: No such file or directory

ALSA lib confmisc.c:392:(snd_func_concat) error evaluating strings

ALSA lib conf.c:4568:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_concat returned error: No such file or directory

ALSA lib confmisc.c:1246:(snd_func_refer) error evaluating name

ALSA lib conf.c:4568:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_refer returned error: No such file or directory

ALSA lib conf.c:5047:(snd_config_expand) Evaluate error: No such file or directory

ALSA lib pcm.c:2565:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM default

AL lib: (EE) ALCplaybackAlsa_open: Could not open playback device 'default': No such file or directory


Blender quit

<<<<<<<<< edit <<<<<<<<<

Since those are all audio files, I tried:

```
./blender -b -noaudio
```

The error messages went away but Blender still wouldn't run

```
Blender quit
```

<<<<<<<<< edit <<<<<<<<<

Okay! I thought that when I got the message "Blender quit", Blender had crashed or something. Wrong! That just means Blender was finished with its tasks -- and because I hadn't given it anything to do, it started and stopped immediately. So I wrote a little hello-world Python script. Works fine. Here's the magic command line.

```
./blender --background --python /opt/hello.py
```

I'm still getting those ALSA warnings, but I'll deal with that another day. Thanks to @brockmann and @susu.
**Solution:**
Download--`https://www.blender.org/download/Blender2.83/blender-2.83.2-linux64.tar.xz/`

Move the downloaded file into a folder. I used /opt/.

`cd` to the folder and Unzip the file: `tar -xf archive.tar.xz`

From that same directory you can launch `./blender`

When Blender successfully finishes doing whatever you told it to do, it will give the message `Blender quit`

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/110680/discussion-on-question-by-etixfilm-how-do-i-install-and-run-blender-2-83-on-cent).

Comment: Anyone running into the same issue on Debian, you can install the required libraries with:
`sudo apt install -y libxi6 libxxf86vm1 libxfixes3 libxrender1 libgl1`

After installing these, both the snap version and the downloaded version should work.